# Disabled a input when another input is filled in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

How to Disabled a input (with javascript) when another input is filled in

Exemple :

http://www.pct.com.tn/index.php?option=com_searchproduct&view=searchproduct&ctg=M&Itemid=48&lang=fr#b

Thanks

Comment: You can do it by listening for key events with javascript.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow ;)

Answer (score 1):

Monitor for on input with javascript and compare the value.

```js
window.onload = function(){
  var boxOne = document.getElementById('inputOne');
  var boxTwo = document.getElementById('inputTwo');
  boxOne.oninput = function(){
    if(this.value != ""){
      //if there is a value
      //change the background color (optional)
      boxTwo.style.backgroundColor = '#999';
      boxTwo.disabled = true;  
    }
    else{
      //if there isn't a value
      boxTwo.disabled = false;
      //change the background color (optional) 
      boxTwo.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
    }
  };
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inputOne" placeholder="type to disable other">
<input type="text" id="inputTwo">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can acheive this by using jquery for keydown event. I have done some sample code based on my understanding to your question. Assume you have two text boxes, on entering a text to any of textbox will lock the other

```
 <input type = 'text' id='firstTextBox'/>
    <input type = 'text' id='secondTextBox'/>

    <script>
    $("input").keydown(function(){
            if($("#firstTextBox").val()!= '')
            {
                $('#secondTextBox').attr('disable', 'disable');
            }
            else if($("#secondTextBox").val()!= '')
            {
                $('#firstTextBox').attr('disable', 'disable');
            }
          else if($("#firstTextBox").val()== '' && $("#secondTextBox").val()== '')
          {
              $('#firstTextBox').removeAttr('disable');
             $("#secondTextBox").removeAttr('disable');
         }
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: What if the user hits the backspace (safari doesn't support keypress with the mac delete key) key? I know that on safari on a mac that onkeypress with a delete key isn't supported which would mean that in some cases on some browsers, the box would be disabled even when there was no value. Use `oninput` instead; it supports all the keys used to type including the backspace (delete) key.

Comment: @www139 : Thankyou! I never knew it. I have modified it as keydown. I read in another thread that keydown is identified for any key pressed. Thanks again! I am upvoting your answer right away.